# Python: if not any trying to understand the difference in handling the output

Tags: python, python-3.x

Checking to see if any of the args were stored true and if not then set them all to true to run all the args.  ie can run one arg or if you don't select one it will run them all.

```
if not any((args.x, args.y, args.z)):
    args.x = args.y = args.z = True '''this works'''

    args.x, args.y, args.z = True '''but this does not work - gives TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable bool object'''
```

But it will work if I make a much more ugly if statement like this.

```
 if args.x is False and args.y is False and args.z is False:
    args.x = args.y = args.z = True '''this works'''
    args.x, args.y, args.z = True '''and this works as well'''
```

Comment: `args.x, args.y, args.z = [True]*3`

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  The second assignment should always fail because it's attempting to unpack a `bool` object, which cannot be unpacked.

Comment: Add a print statement to the second example inside the `if` block so you know you're actually entering it. Because the only reason that code should have worked for you is if you never actually made it into the block.

Comment: Why are you comparing usin `is`? Use `==` Use `is` only for `if something is None:` .. or if you want to check identity

Comment: @PatrickArtner Yeah, that could be why he thinks the second block is running when it actually isn't. A more equivalent statement to the first example would be `if not args.x and not args.y and not args.z:`.

Comment: I tested the [True]*3 and the True, True, True and both work.  The script was written and given to me to test, and I didn't like how it was originally laid out, the is was used in the original, but he didn't have a working out put.  I got it to work with putting each variable = True on a separate line but it seamed bulky to me.

Comment: @PatrickArtner he used  is false  because when using pycharm he would get this:  PEP 8: comparison to False should be 'if cond is False:' or 'if not cond:'  if he used == false.  I didn't like that so started with the if not any but that is where I got suck, I didn't realize I needed to balance out the true to match the variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have 3 variables on the left side of an assignment, you need to have 3 on the right side as well. This:

```
args.x, args.y, args.z = True
```

has 3 values on the left and only 1 on the right. Try doing this:

```
args.x, args.y, args.z = True, True, True
```

or this:

```
args.x, args.y, args.z = [True for i in range(3)]
```

This statement:

```
args.x = args.y = args.z = True
```

works the same as this:

```
args.x = True
args.y = True
args.z = True
```

which is legal python code.

Comment: You're mostly correct, but `args.x = args.y = args.z = True` does not work the way you describe. If it did, and `x` or `y` were weird `property` things that didn't necessarily return what they were set to, you'd have unpredictable behavior. The ordering is also wrong; Python assigns from left to right, even here. The actual behavior is more like `__unnamed = True`, `args.x = __unnamed`, `args.y = __unnamed`, `args.z = __unnamed` (`__unnamed` is actually a value shoved on the frame's stack, duplicated to fill all the assignment targets). You're probably thinking of `C` assignment semantics.